# Dired, async copy files

Tags: dired

Windows 10, Emacs 25, Dired.

I tried to copy a lot of files in `dired`, and Emacs "freeze" while copying.
What is the best package for async copy/move files in Dired?

Comment: A [web search for `dired async`](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=dired+async&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) pulls up [`dired-async-mode`](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async/blob/master/dired-async.el) as its first hit.  Did you try it?

Comment: I changed "Dired+" to "Dired" in your question, because I think it is about doing asynchronous copies in Dired. [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) does not offer anything specifically for aysnchronous behavior. Presumably, any library or other code that does will work fine with both vanilla Dired and with Dired+ (which just extends vanilla Dired).

Comment: I found variable "(dired-async-mode 1)". If set true then asyn is on. It's built in variable. OK. But the next question is: When finish copy/move why not show finish message? Something like "The all files was copied"